# Is Netbeans better than Eclipse for web service development ?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, netbeans, apache-axis

I just started 5 hours ago with web services. I have some background but now I am looking more into it. 
I tried both Eclipse (with Axis 2) and Netbeans. At the first glance Netbeans seems far less complex to use regarding web services. I don't understand why there is the need for stubs and handlers generation in Eclipse (1000 lines of code for a simple web service) when Netbeans does not have this? I want to use Eclipse (because I use it for everything else) but it drives me crazy when I see the big difference from Netbeans in developing web services.

Is it something I do wrong if I use Axis ? Do you know some other framework to make things easier? 
With netbeans I followed [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html) simple tutorial and everything is nice and easy. 
Please recommend me some framework, tutorials or whatever is better for Eclipse. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis 2 is only web service runtime, you can try Apache CXF as well. When it comes to web service development Eclipse is a very good and complex tool, I used it in many projects. Another must-have tool for web service development is SoapUI. Good luck!